# Eclipse CWT crashes with grey window

Tags: linux, eclipse, opencv, crash

I'm writing an OpenCV program for university and got some troubles with Eclipse.

I am running a 64bit Linux Mint (13) with Eclipse Juno. I installed OpenCV using [this guide](http://www.samontab.com/web/2012/06/installing-opencv-2-4-1-ubuntu-12-04-lts/), except I installed Version 2.4.3. 
Since the project my partner on MacOS shared with me didn't work, I created a plain C++ Project. I added the information needed in the build settings as followed:

```
Cross GCC Compiler -> -I -> "/usr/local/include/opencv" and "/usr/local/include/opencv2"
Cross G++ Linker -> Libraries -> -I -> "cv" and "highui"
                              -> -L -> "/usr/local/lib"
```

This is the code I'm using. Right, it does nothing:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    return 0;
}
```

So, everytime I'm running this, i get an ugly grey window, like a message window would look like, but nothing in it. This is the same es the actual program with code in it, so it's nothing to do with OpenCV commands.
Sometimes, this window disappears with killing Eclipse, with doens't response then. Sometimes, it even survives that and I have to start a new X session.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

The error messages you can see are not related to the crash itself, but shown before.
Sometimes it just says "Binary not found", which those messages come from. It somehow doesnt find the libraries.

This is pkg-config --libs opencv

```
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_contrib.so 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_gpu.so 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_legacy.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.so 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_nonfree.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_photo.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.so 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_ts.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.so 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videostab.so
```

This is pkg-config --cflags opencv

```
-I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include
```

It hast to do something with my OpenCV/CWT setup I guess. Since I tried out a lot of variations, does anybody got any idea what I did wrong?